# EF Core 3.1, Anonymous class loads subclass but named class does not after Take()

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I noticed a somewhat strange behavior in EF Core (atleast in versions 3.1.4 and 3.1.8) and I wonder if I'm doing something wrong or why this is happening.

When I use Include() and select into an anomymous class the subclass is loaded as expected but with a named class in the select statement the sublass is null. The difference only happens after I do .Take(x) if I enumerate the list before Take() everything is loaded but if I don't the subclass is null.

Named class:

```
var items = _context.TABLE.Include(a => a.SUBTABLE).Select(a => new NAMEDCLASS { 
    item = a,
    ...
});
```

Anonymous class:

```
var items = _context.TABLE.Include(a => a.SUBTABLE).Select(a => new { 
    item = a,
    ...
});
```

If I enumerate at this stage both are the same. But after i run:

```
var pagedItems = items.Take(10);
```

They start to differ, with the named class SUBTABLE is null but with the anonymous class the SUBTABLE is loaded as expected. If I debug and enumerate items before the Take() both are the same again.

the named class:

```
public class NAMEDCLASS : IListRow<NAMEDCLASS> {
    public TABLE item { get; set; }
    ...

    public string Identifier {
        get => TABLE.guid.ToString();
    }
}
```

the interface only standardize a unique id

```
public interface IListRow<T> {
    public string Identifier { get; }
}
```

Why is this happening? is it a bug or am I doing something wrong? The problem is that I use the interface on the NAMEDCLASS to do some filtering and stuff so I would prefer to keep the named class if possible.

Edited to add 3.1 in the title

Comment: Looks like a bug. Try to add AsNoTracking(), possible it is a problem with Change Tracker.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, tried it but it made no difference unfortunately...

Comment: Looks like EFC 3.x defect(bug), because the same works in current EFC 5.0 preview. There is nothing you can do, EFC 5.0 release by plan would be the next month, I don't think they will provide fixes for 3.x

Comment: I tested mine. It works fine. You try to create another new class without IListRow<NAMEDCLASS> and Identitifer. Just class with TABLE property only. Then re-run see if new class still same issue or not.